# Pandas shift moving discarded elements to the beginning

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I can't find a simple way to shift a pandas DataFrame, but instead of discarding the values at the end, moving them to the beginning.

e.g.

Using this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(val=[10, 20, 30, 40]))
df.shift(1)
```

I obtain:

```
   val
0  NaN
1   10
2   20
3   30
```

But I would like to obtain:

```
   val
0   40
1   10
2   20
3   30
```

(the 40 that has been discarded should fill the empty space it has been left)

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're after [`np.roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html), this will roll elements pass the end and wrap them back to the beginning along an axis:

```
In [121]:

np.roll(df,1)
Out[121]:
array([[40],
       [10],
       [20],
       [30]], dtype=int64)

In [123]:

df['val'] = np.roll(df, 1)
df
Out[123]:
   val
0   40
1   10
2   20
3   30
```

Comment: Awesome man, that's exactly what I wanted. I'll wait a little before accepting your answer, to see if there is any other approach.